# Loading partial YAML into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml, partial

I have the following YAML configuration for each instance.

```
prod:
    login: A
    var1: VP1
    var2: VP2
QA:
   login: B
   var1: QP1
   var2: QP2
```

I want to load

- Only QA block into a dictionary if my current environment is QA .
- Only Prod block into dict, if my current environment is prod.

How can I conditionally load a block of YAML into a dict?

The downstream code is something like this

```
#bin/ksh
login = {login}
var1 = {var1}
var2 = {var2}
```

I want these values to be resolved in ksh script based on the environment.

Comment: You'll have to ingest the entire YAML, and then take only what you want

Comment: I added details. loading everything will create a conflict

Comment: I don't see how loading that YAML will lead to conflict, as you'd get the following dict: `{'prod': {'login':"A", 'var1':"VP1", 'var2':"VP2"}, 'QA': {'login':"B", 'var1':"QP1", 'var2':"QP2"}}`. You can easily query that dict for `prod` or `QA` and get conflict-less data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just load the entire file and then only grab the stuff under the key you want.

```
with open('data.yml') as f:
    d = yaml.load(f.read())
    print yaml.dump(d['QA'])
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
import yaml
import socket

qa="172.27.139.94"
prod="172.27.139.95"
ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
if ip == qa:
    yml_dic = yaml.load(open('yamlconfig.yml', 'r'))["QA"]
elif ip == prod:
    yml_dic = yaml.load(open('yamlconfig.yml', 'r'))["prod"]

print yml_dic
```

Comment: It's traditional to give at least some explanation of what your proposed solution actually does.

Comment: step 1: getting ip address from our environment

Comment: step 2: if the ip address matching with QA then will read the data from QA section

Comment: step 3: if the ip address matching with production ip then it will read the data from production section

Comment: Note: this case will apply if you dont know where you are. i mean where do you deployed the code